# JdbcTemplate's update method does not update without PreparedStatementCreator

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE user_use_case_control (
id integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10, INCREMENT BY 1) not null,
name varchar(20) not null,
start_date timestamp not null,
end_date timestamp null,
duration timestamp null,
status varchar(20) null,
user_id varchar(20) not null );
```

I am working with Spring Framework 4.0.5, with **JdbcTemplate**,  and I have the following insertion method (part of the method)

**Alpha**

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update(

        new PreparedStatementCreator()  {

            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql,  
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

                ps.setString(1, userControl.getName());
                ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp( userControl.getStartDate().getTime() ));
                ps.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp( userControl.getEndDate().getTime() ));
                ps.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp( userControl.getDuration().getTime() ));
                ps.setString(5, userControl.getStatus());
                ps.setString(6, userControl.getUserId());

           return ps;
          }
    }, keyHolder);
```

Observe:

- I am using `PreparedStatementCreator` to get the generated key.
- I am using `ps.setTimestamp` and `new Timestamp`

The insertion method works fine.

The problem is for the update.

I have the following:

**Beta**

```
@Override
public UserControl update(UserControl userControl) {

    logger.info("UserControlJdbcRepository - update {}", userControl.toString());

    String sql = "UPDATE user_use_case_control uucc " +
                 "SET uucc.name=?, uucc.start_date=?, uucc.end_date=?, uucc.duration=?, uucc.status=? " +
                 "WHERE uucc.id=?";


    int result = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,
                    userControl.getName(),
                    new Timestamp( userControl.getStartDate().getTime() ),
                    new Timestamp( userControl.getEndDate().getTime() ),
                    new Timestamp( userControl.getDuration().getTime() ),
                    userControl.getStatus(),
                    userControl.getUserId());

    logger.info("result {}", result);
…
```

- with logger I can see the object and all their variables are not null

The **problem** is: the `jdbcTemplate.update` **does not** update nothing!

Same situation if I use

```
int result = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,
                 userControl.getName(),
                 userControl.getStartDate(),
                 userControl.getEndDate(),
                 userControl.getDuration(),
                 userControl.getStatus(),
                 userControl.getUserId());
```

If I do a debug and logger with DEBUG level, I can see the following:

```
Executing prepared SQL update
Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE user_use_case_control uucc SET uucc.name=?, uucc.start_date=?, uucc.end_date=?, uucc.duration=?, uucc.status=? WHERE uucc.id=?]
SQL update affected 0 rows
SQLWarning ignored: SQL state '02000', error code '-1100', message [no data]
```

I dont understand why happens this.

If the logger has INFO level none error appears, I mean some exception does not arise.

If I change the method with the following:

**Omicron**

```
int result = this.jdbcTemplate.update(

        new PreparedStatementCreator()  {

            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

                ps.setString(1, userControl.getName());
                ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp( userControl.getStartDate().getTime() ));
                ps.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp( userControl.getEndDate().getTime() ));
                ps.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp( userControl.getDuration().getTime() ));
                ps.setString(5, userControl.getStatus());
                ps.setInt(6, userControl.getId());

                return ps;
            }

        });

logger.info("result {}", result);
```

Just then: It works totally fine.

Observe:

- Alpha, Beta and Omicron uses `ps.setTimestamp` and `new Timestamp`

Questions:

1. Why **Beta** fails? (message [no data])
2. Why only works the updating with `PreparedStatementCreator`?

**Note:** I have other Repositories and the `update` methods based on **Beta**, working without `PreparedStatementCreator`, work fine.

Just to highlight about the other repositories:

- some of them have no a `timestamp` field, just have `date` in the db table schema.
- some of them neither have a `timestamp` field nor a `date` field in the db table schema.

Therefore this weird behaviour only appears for **update** when the `timestamp` field is involved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are showing two different method calls for the id used in the update - userControl.getId() and userControl.getUserId() - could that be the reason one update works and the other on dosn't?

Comment: Oh…. that's the problem when I work many hours…. thanks a lot!